# Hexadecimal encoding in Go

Tags: go, encoding, decoding

i want to compare two sequences of bytes in hex using golang. I'm a beginner and can't figure out how to create the variable of bytes from Hex. Below is the code of what I'm trying to do.

```
import "bytes" 

static-bytes := //Set hex here, something like 504B0506
static-bytes2 := //Set hex here, something like 504B

fmt.Println(bytes.Contains(static-bytes, static-bytes2))
```

Comment: You can't use hyphens in variable names, but you can use hex to represent numeric literals: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals e.g. `static_bytes := []byte{0x50, 0x4B, 0x05, 0x06}`

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a hexadecimal string, you can use the [encoding/hex](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex) package, specifically [DecodeString](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString), to convert the string into bytes. For example:

```
b1, _ := hex.DecodeString("737461636b6f766572666c6f77")
```

Or, if you are using integer literals in hexadecimal notation as mentioned by @Adrian, you can use the following:

```
b2 := []byte{ 0x6f, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x66, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x77 }
```

This will enable you to compare the sequences as intended:

```
b1, _ := hex.DecodeString("737461636b6f766572666c6f77")
b2 := []byte{ 0x6f, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x66, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x77}
println(bytes.Contains(b1, b2))
```